# Angular component state like React use state hook

Tags: angular, components, state

I came to Angular from React experience .

In react I use the  Use State hook or set State in classes for example to handle component state .so if state changes the component re renders to reflect changes

I ended up making a parent child components and passes @input to the child and in the child I used ngOnChange

And this done the trick

But what is the standard and simplest way to do it instead of adding a parent extra component since no job for the parent component except passing @input to do this trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways by which I do this, 2 of which are -

1. Using getter and setter for the variable.

```
export class MyComponent {

 private _myProp: any;

 public get myProp(): any {
   return this._myPorp;
 }

 public set myProp(val: any) {
   this._myProp = val;
   // enter code here which you want to execute on property value change.
 }

 constructor () {
   // notice that I am using myProp and not _myProp
   this.myProp = 'some arbitrary value';
 }
}
```

2. Using rxjs Subject - [link](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/subject)

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

...
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
 myPropSubject = new Subject();

 constructor() {
   this.myPropSubject.subscribe((val) => {
     // enter code here which you want to execute on property value change.
   });
 }

 ngOnInit(): void {
   this.myPropSubject.next('some arbitrary value');
 }
}
```